# groupBy() with broken hashCode()?

Tags: java, groovy, rx-java

Currently my application is trying to use RxJava [groupBy()](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/Observable.html#groupBy%28rx.functions.Func1%29) for what theoretically should be an easy task. The problem is that the `hashCode()` method of the class (MyClass) I'm trying to group by is broken.

What I've done to work around it is as follows:

```
myValues
    // Group by the string representation, rather than actual class
    .groupBy { it.toString() }
    .map { GroupedObservable.from(new MyClass(it.getKey()), it) }
```

Where MyClass is set up like so:

```
class MyClass {
    MyClass(String initialString) {
        // Some constructor here
    }
}
```

The problem is that `GroupedObservable.from()` is a deprecated method.

Normally I'm all in favor of fixing the `hashCode()` method to support a proper `groupBy()`, but this is in an external library. I tried sub-classing and over-riding the `hashCode()` method there, but I still have issues because I need to map back to the original class.

Is there a proper way to work around a broken `hashCode()` method in RxJava?

Comment: The `hashCode()` method produces a null pointer exception.

Comment: I'm not sure how to write it in groovy. But something like `.map { go -> go.map(v -> new Pair(new MyClass(go.key), v) ) }` should work